# Address picker not suggesting fields?

Tags: forms, autocomplete, street-address

I'm trying to use an address picker on my form, located here:

http://realendeavors.com/dmv-form/htmlform.htm

I've followed all the steps outlined here: https://github.com/sgruhier/typeahead-addresspicker

Any idea why, when typing in a sample address into the address field, no addresses are popping up?

Answer (score 0):

In console is error:

```
This service requires an API key.  For more information on 
authentication and Google Maps Javascript API services please see: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key
```

Comment: Ah ok! Where would I input the API key once I've gotten it?

Comment: You need to put it in link of script
`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>`